# Official way to write xcode

Tags: xcode, naming-conventions

What's the official way to write: `Xcode`, `XCode`, `xcode`, ... ? I have seen it writing numerous ways and want to be sure that I use it correctly.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: But Xcode is an IDE...

Comment: @BoltClock: How to spell it isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a picture is worth a thousand words

[image]

Comment: Indeed, or when you click on the "Xcode" menu and choose "About Xcode" and see the dialog box that says "Xcode". Or the launch screen that says "Welcome to Xcode" and "Create a new Xcode project" and "Learn about using Xcode," ad nauseum. The app itself should serve as the canonical answer. :)

Comment: Alright I better not see another XCode on a forum ever again! :) Thanks