# UITableViewCell width

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view placed in a navigation controller. Cells of the table view are smaller in width than the original and the background is an image. How can i set the "selected color"? here is my code so far:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ApplicationCell";

    ApplicationCell *cell = (ApplicationCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    }
return cell;
}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
    {
        cellContentView = [[CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCellContentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.contentView.bounds, 0.0, 1.0) cell:self];
        cellContentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        cellContentView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;

        //here i'm making the cells smaller in width than the rest of the tableView
        CGRect framme = cellContentView.frame;

        framme.size.width = framme.size.width-58;
        //set the left space
        framme.origin.x = framme.origin.x+29;

        [cellContentView setFrame:framme];
        [self.contentView addSubview:cellContentView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

[image: here is my table view unselected]

[image: selected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TableViewCell`s have a `backgroundView` and a `selectedBackgroundView`. Use these for the background and only put the labels and image views in the `contentView`.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
    {
        UIView* backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        UIView* visibleBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(29.0f, 0.0f, backgroundView.bounds.size.width - 58.0f, backgroundView.bounds.size.height)];
        // configure the visibleBackgroundView with the color you want for unselected cell here
        [backgroundView addSubview:visibleBackgroundView];
        self.backgroundView = backgroundView;

        UIView* selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        UIView* visibleSelectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(29.0f, 0.0f, backgroundView.bounds.size.width - 58.0f, backgroundView.bounds.size.height)];
        // configure the visibleSelectedBackgroundView with the color you want for selection here
        [selectedBackgroundView addSubview:visibleSelectedBackgroundView];
        self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;

        // configure your content view with all the labels you need here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: ok that works but the frame of the selected is not the smaller one!

Comment: No, you have to set a `selectedBackgroundView` that is the full size and then, as you did in your example, add a subview to that backgroundView that has the appropriate size. This is also what you should do with the `backgroundView` property.

Comment: aha got it let me try it and let you know! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: could you please give me an example code cause i think i messed it up

Comment: ok i did it using something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003569/uitableview-cell-selectedbackgroundview-without-showing-backgroundview

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCell is a subclass of UiView so you can use all the UIView class properties on it like backgroundColor etc.
As Madboy mentioned its also has backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView also as its properties so you can play with theses properties to make it a customised cell.