# Get path of file from clipboard in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, clipboard, nspasteboard

I would like my app to get the full path of the file copied to the clipboard before.

I tried this:

```
NSPasteboard *p = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSString *path = [[p readObjectsForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString class], nil] options:options] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This only returns the filename, not the path.

Can you help me?

Comment: Btw, [it's called Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5725282/457406), but it is not relevant for this question anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSArray *classes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL class]];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey];

NSArray *fileURLs =
[pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];
```

That's straight from Apple's [Pasteboard Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008099).

Comment: Indeed, file URLs should be preferred over pathnames in all modern code whenever you have a choice.

Comment: But I need the path, not the file URL... Is this possible?

Comment: After you get the `NSURL` object, invoke `-path` on it.

Comment: @Oskar: Are you *sure* you need the path? Nearly everything in Cocoa has a method that accepts a URL at this point. (Sorry if I seem hung up on this; it's very common for people to unnecessarily use paths when they should be using URLs.)

Comment: I tried it with the file url but it didn't work. I need it for an uploader (ASIHTTPRequest)

Comment: How can I do this in a scripting language (applescript, bash, python, etc)?